# SQL Error message relating to length of identifier

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005, .net-assembly

I get the following error, but not quite sure what it means:

> Error message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The identifier that
>   starts with  '[DEFAULT], 1 AS rowJoiner FROM (dasolPSDev.dbo.BB03_12
>   INNER JOIN dasolPSDev.dbo.BB03_10 ON dasolPSDev.dbo.BB03_12.caseid = '
>   is too long. Maximum length is 128. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.InternalNextResult(Boolean
>   ignoreNonFatalMessages) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.NextResult() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderSmi(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at
>   PowerStatTable.CentileGenerator.LoadResult(String strQry, Int32
>   currRowNo) at
>   PowerStatTable.CentileGenerator.LoadMedianTable(OutputMatrix outMtx)
>   at
>   PowerStatTable.CentileGenerator.CaclulateMedian(CentileStdErrCalculator
>   calc, Int32 prevCol, Int32 colIndex) at
>   PowerStatTable.MedianGenerator.Start() at
>   PowerStatTable.TableGenerator.Start(ApplicationContext appContext,
>   String strUID, Int32 seqId, Int32 flagProgress, String strTpf, Int32
>   outputType) at StoredProcedures.CreatePowerStatTable(SqlString strUID,
>   Int32 seqId, Int32 flagProgress, Int32 outputType)

What is the 128 character limit for?  I am using C# and SQL Server 2005 and editing someone elses code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sysname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) data type has a maximum of 128 characters. Note that the error is showing part of a SQL command, starting at [Default]. The process you are editing is generating an invalid sql statement - it is trying to treat that entire text as a field or table name. Go back and check the code that generates the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server thinks that you are referring to an object with the following string as the name

```
'[DEFAULT], 1 AS rowJoiner FROM (dasolPSDev.dbo.BB03_12 INNER JOIN dasolPSDev.dbo.BB03_10 ON dasolPSDev.dbo.BB03_12.caseid = '
```

Obviously, you're not trying to do that; so some part of the process to create the SQL statement is not set up properly.